# How do I disable a keyboard shortcut in gnome-shell?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

There are tutorials all over the web on how to set various functionalities to activate on a keyboard shortcut, but so far I'm unable to figure out how to *un-set* a keyboard shortcut.  That is, how do I set a keyboard shortcut to *disabled* once I've already set it to something else?

For example, say I want to change the keyboard shortcut for "Launch Terminal".  I go into *System Settings*, select *Keyboard > Shortcuts* and under *Launchers*, next to *Launch Terminal* I click on the word `Disabled` which then changes to `New shortcut`.  I hit `Ctrl+t` or something like that and now the shortcut is set.

How now do I change it back to `Disabled`?

Comment: It would be far easier to answer this question if you explain what mechanism you used to set the shortcut. As it is, I could guess at least a half dozen different ways you _might_ have done it.

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail to that effect.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Is this (similar to) what you see?

[image: GNOME Shell Keyboard Shortcuts]

If so, try clicking *on the activated keybinding* (e.g. "Ctrl+Alt+T" in the screenshot<sup>1</sup>) and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to *clear* it (as mentioned at the bottom of the window)

(No idea how to remove a disabled shortcut, `gconf-editor` maybe?)

<sub>*(1)* which I snitched from [this blog](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/12/top-10-gnome-shell-keyboard-shortcuts/)</sub>

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  Honestly, I tried everything to un-set that save reading the fine print at the bottom :-/

Comment: @DanielQuinn it happens to us all at some point ;)

Comment: @msw: This is just what I was about to say... `:)`

Comment: @DanielQuinn I got into that dialogue and also didn't see the instruction to hit Backspace; so I had to google this answer. You're a hero for asking the question.

Comment: I'm using Debian 7.8 in portuguese and the bottom text says to press "barra de espaço para limpar" (spacebar to clear), but not working. Backspace is correct. Thanks.

Comment: I too didn't have the revolutionary idea of reading the entire window... :/ Woe betide ye who wish to redefine Backspace, I guess!

Comment: gnome 3.22 has no textual hint anymore. would never make it without this answer...

Comment: No hint on the window and on a dialog. It just says press ESC to cancel, but using Backspace on the assignment dialog is key here. @sr_ thx!

Comment: Wow, that was completely unintuitive (Gnome 3 with Debian 9).