# Disabling keyboard shortcut for changing display setup in gnome-shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

When I press the right super key + P, gnome-shell switchtes between different display settings (how my monitors are arranged and what there resoluiton is). Sometimes I press the combination accidentally which is really annoying.

I looked through the gnome keybaord settings, and there are all kind of shortcuts. But this one I can not find.

Where is it located and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually use gnome (I installed Ubuntu and just use unity), but when I used gnome I set custom shortcuts, and I've done some reading around to check. Some OSs may need dconf instead of gconf.

The answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34085/how-do-i-disable-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-gnome-shell) shows how to change keyboard shortcuts using gconf-editor. You need to select the unwanted shortcut in gnome tweak-tools or gconf-editor and press backspace to clear it.

Alternative methods are given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68463/how-to-disable-global-super-p-shortcut) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20113/how-to-stop-mod4-p-from-switching-the-display), the questions are on askubuntu, but they're gnome specific questions.

Comment: Well, the solution was in one of your [links](/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys): /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/video-out has to be set to nothing in dconf-editor

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you to try this (it works for me):

Go in the dconf-editor via the command "dconf-editor" in a terminal, then go at:

```
/org/gnome/mutter/keybindings/switch-monitor
```

and disable "use default value" and delete:

```
'<Super>p',
```